# Do-While statement stuck in infinite loop

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop, do-while

I've been staring at this for what seems like hours and I cannot for the life of me figure out why the output when run is stuck in a loop, like so (yes, I have now just correct the spelling of estimated):

Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches.
Your future child is estmated to grow to 4 feet and 10 inches

This happens every time I am writing loops.

> //Allows keyboard to be used
>           Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
>
> ```
>     //Allows user to input numbers
>     System.out.println("Enter the gender of your future child. Use 1 for Female and 0 for Male: ");
>     int Gender = keyboardInput.nextInt();
>     System.out.println("Enter the height in feet, then in inches of the mom: ");
>     int MomHeight = keyboardInput.nextInt();
>     System.out.println("Enter the height in feet, then the height in inches of the dad: ");
>     int DadHeight = keyboardInput.nextInt();
>
>     int female;
>     int male;
>     int HeightFeet;
>     int HeightInches;
>
>     DecimalFormat feet = new DecimalFormat("#0");
>     DecimalFormat inches = new DecimalFormat("#0");
>
>     //Loop statements
>     while (Gender == 0)
>     {
>        male = (MomHeight * 13 / 12 + DadHeight) / 2;
>        HeightFeet = male / 12;
>        HeightInches = male % 12;   
>
>     System.out.print("Your future child is estimated to grow to " + feet.format(HeightFeet));
>     System.out.print(" feet and " + inches.format(HeightInches));
>     System.out.print(" inches.");
>     System.out.println("");
>     }
>
>     while (Gender == 1)
>     {
>         female = (DadHeight * 12 /13 + MomHeight) /2;
>         HeightFeet = female / 12;
>          HeightInches= female % 12;
>
>     System.out.print("Your future child is estmated to grow to " + feet.format(HeightFeet));
>     System.out.print(" feet and " + inches.format(HeightInches));
>     System.out.print(" inches.");
>     System.out.println("");
>     } } }
> ```

Comment: If you never change Gender within the loop, how will it ever exit. This is not a programming question but rather a basic logic question.

Comment: You need to use `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: It would really help everyone if you'd follow the Java naming conventions.

Comment: I corrected it all in what I am doing. It's not like we all don't know what it is referring to. Relax. It's not like it was finalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loops, `Gender` is never modified. So you loop indeed forever.
Now, I don't think you need a `while` statement.
An `if else if` statement would be preferable as you don't take new input from the user to loop but you want to apply a processing according to a specific condition (male or female gender).

By the way, you should name your variable `gender` rather than `Gender` to respect Java naming conventions :

```
if (gender == 0){
      ...
}

else if (gender == 1){
       ...
}
```

If you would to repeat all the processing multiple times, you could use a loop over all:

```
 boolean again = false;
 do{
       if (gender == 0){
          ...
       }

       else if (gender == 1){
           ...
       }
       ...
      again = keyboardInput.nextBoolean();

 } while (again);
```

Comment: I usually don't capitalize my variables. I don't know what my brain is doing today. 

The if else if worked like a charm. Thank you SO much.

Comment: You are very welcome :) I also show you an example to use a `do-while` that makes sense to repeat the whole process.

Comment: Yes, I did see that. Again, thank you so so much. I can't even begin to tell you how much I appreciate this. Makes much more sense than the stuff I was looking at trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

In order to exit a loop, you need the condition to become false after the loop has executed after your desired number of times.

Also in the above code, you seem to be making a choice between the statements to be executed, rather than running a traditional loop. Consider using a "if" statement

```
while (Gender == 0){
//Do this
}

while (Gender == 1){
//Do this instead
}
```

If you wanted the loop to exit after printing the output statements "X" times, you would rather base the condition on a count variable.

So making a choice is based on the **Gender** variable and printing the statements is based on the **count** variable.

```
//Assume print is to be done 2 times

int count = 1;

if(Gender == 0){
//Female selection
while( count < 3 ){
 // Execute female code
 count++;
}
else if(Gender == 1){
//Male selection
while( count < 3 ){
 // Execute male code
 count++;
}
```